# border around a cardview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, cardview

I want to put a blue border around my cardview, but I can't put it on. It works on Constraint Layout tag but not on CardView

card_edge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
  <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#3683D6" />
  <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

item_game_list.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:background="@drawable/card_edge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        .
        .
        .

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: use app:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/card_edge" instead of android:background="@drawable/card_edge"

Comment: Make nested cardviews. Give outer cardview a color and inner cardview 1 dp margen.

Comment: within CardView it does not accept calling @drawable in ´app:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/card_edge @RudraRokaya´

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your drawable file i.e. @drawable/card_edge inside the child layout (in my case LinearLayout but You can use any layout as per your requirements.) of cardview and it will create UI as per your requirement.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/card_edge"
        >
        .
        .
        .
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: `android:elevation="5dp"` won't work for older android devices prior to API 21. And no one does card elevation that way, people use `app:cardlEevation="5dp"`

Comment: yeah, you are right. Point noted. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: It worked, I just adjusted the card_edge margins, thank you